# How to prioratize onPaste over onKeyPress in Safari

Tags: javascript, reactjs, safari, event-handling, dom-events

I'm using this Javascript code to build an input field which should only take input if a number is entered. But a user should be able to paste a number using <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>. This logic seems to work fine in case of Chrome but in Safari, `OnKeyPress` takes priority over `OnPaste` and `handleOnKeyPress` prevents the event when <kbd>V</kbd> is clicked. How do I enable user from pasting a number but disable entering letter <kbd>v</kbd> in safari.

```
const handleOnKeyPress = e => {
// Take only input between 0-9
   if(!RegExp(/^([0-9]*)$/).test(e.key)) e.preventDefault()
}

const handleOnPaste = e => {
// Print the data which is being being pasted.
   console.log(e.clipboardData.getData('Text'))
}

<input onKeyPress={handleOnKeyPress} onPaste={e => {handleOnPaste(e)}} />
```

Comment: do: `var ctrlKeyPressed =e.ctrlKey` where `e` is a keyBoardEvent object. Then, allow the key press if accompanied by the control key.

Comment: I think you can also check to see if the event itself is a ClipBoardEvent type. Then only preventDefault otherwise.

Comment: Thanks Randy. It makes sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the comment from [Randy Casburn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9078341/randy-casburn). I changed handleOnKeyPress. Small change makes a lot more sense now.

```
const handleOnKeyPress = e => {
   if(!RegExp(/^([0-9]*)$/).test(e.key) && !e.metaKey) e.preventDefault()
}
```